# does not have permission to perform (sdb:ListDomains)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

When I run the Kinesis sample, I get this error:

```
Caught Exception: User (arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/user_name) does not have permission to perform (sdb:ListDomains) on resource (arn:aws:sdb:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:domain/). Contact account owner.
```

What is the policy name that I need to attach for the user in-order to grant access to perform perform (sdb:ListDomains) ?

Answer (score 2):

Only 6 AWS managed policies mention `sdb` explicitly:

```
 - AmazonElasticMapReduceReadOnlyAccess
 - AmazonElasticMapReduceRole 
 - AmazonElasticMapReduceforEC2Role
 - ReadOnlyAccess
 - AmazonElasticMapReduceFullAccess
 - SecurityAudit
```

`ReadOnlyAccess` has `sdb:List*` attached so it seems like the most sensible if you are running a sample app.

Otherwise create your own policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "sdb:ListDomains"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```